# Issues running commands

Tags: sudo, command-line

Every time I run a command I get this back.

```
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?
christopher@christopher:~$
```

This didn't start happening until I changed my device name.

Comment: What commands are you trying to run?

Comment: apt-get autoclean

Comment: sometimes it works, but then when trying to get updates before installing something I get it then too.

Comment: You should be using `sudo apt-get autoclean`.

Answer (score 1):

This part from the error message says everything: `...are you root?`

So, use:

```
sudo your_command_here
```

This is the way, in general, to run a command as root.

See also [`man sudo`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/sudo).

Answer (score 0):

This error is due to root privileges.

certain commands require root privileges to run.
so use `sudo` before the command.
For further information use manual page of `sudo`.Type the following for  manual page.

```
man sudo
```

it give you a detailed information about `sudo`.

Answer (score 0):

The action your are trying to do have to start from root directory and a normal user cannot access root directly with normal powers. So he needs root powers to access the root folders and he can do it with command sudo.

so execute your command with sudo before it or turn into with `sudo -i` and then run in it. both will do the same.

[If you want to more about Root and sudo Then click here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo)